# GhostScript transparency in image lost when converting to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have PDF file with the transparency / shadow which I created in CorelDraw. What I'm trying to do is to convert RGB PDF into CMYK PDF using GhostScript. Ideally, transparency should be flattened in the converted PDF file. Not ideally, left as is. The transparency in the converted file is replaced with white background. I'm not sure if there is a switch that can leave PDF transparencies alone or flatten transparency.

This is my code:

```
gs -o converted.pdf 
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged 
-dDownsampleMonoImages=false
-dDownsampleGrayImages=false 
-dDownsampleColorImages=false
-dAutoFilterColorImages=false 
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false
-dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode 
-dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode
-dEncodeColorImages=false 
-dEncodeGrayImages=false 
-dEncodeMonoImages=false 
BadFile.pdf
```

I have also tried simple PDF to PDF conversion using:

```
gs -o converted.pdf
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
BadFile.pdf
```

Still the same result.

I'm attaching image files that show what happens. BadFile.jpg is what PDF with transparency / shadow looks like and converted.png is what the result. Any suggestions or help is appreciated. Maybe there is another software that can convert RGB PDF into CMYK PDF while maintaining transparencies and shadows? I work in PHP.

Thanks

[image: BadFile.pdf][image: converted.pdf]

[PDF file](http://www.filedropper.com/04acrobatprotestingfilebad)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to KenS to pointing out to provide more info. I have attached PDF file that I'm using to test. I'm using widows 10 with GS 9.19 64bit. I left -dColorConversionStrategy unchanged to eliminate that variable. The result is the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Image files are pretty much useless for determining a problem, you should link to the original PDF file. It would also be helpful (since you are creating the file yourself) to remove the irrelevant portions, such as the image and text. You don't say what version of Ghostscript you are using, nor on which operating system. Finally you say you want to convert from RGB to CMYK, but you have set ColorConversionStrategy to LeaveColorUnchanged, which certainly won;t do that. I doubt you really want transparency flattened, as that just produces an image of the whole page.

Comment: Thanks @KenS. I have updated questions. Completely forgot to provide that info. I was wondering if in GS you can flatten transparencies like in Acrobat, there it would rasterize only potion which has transparency. If it is not possible to do in GS I would prefer to leave transparencies as is in the new PDF file (colour converted). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You cannot render only a portion of a page. Any page which has transparency will be rendered to an image if you 'flatten' transparency. I'll look at the PDF file directly.

Comment: Well, this looks like a bug, I'[d suggest you report it as such. Since you are creating the file yourself, it would help to simplify it by removing the extra image and the text, leaving just the offending area.